# jquery accelerate animation to the end and hurry setTimeout for next slide

Tags: jquery, settimeout, window-resize

I am trying to program a jQuery re-sizable slideshow. By re-sizable I mean that slideshow elements are re-sized whenever the screen is re-sized.

I have the core of the slideshow working. But, **I want to accelerate the current's slide animation whenever the browser screen is re-sized, and then hurry the last setTimeout (which is to call the fitting elements to current window size and animate these) that has been set when the current's animation was started**.

Right now, when the screen is re-sized, the animation of the current slide continues at the previous window ratio size. When this slide's animation is finished, then the next animation is loaded with the appropriate size.

You can view a sample of the slideshow here (re-size your window to better understand what I am trying to communicate): http://websonalized.com/myplugin/myplugin.php

This is the function where I call functions to fit the slide's element, animate, and the function itself for a never ending loop:

```
function recycle(){

    //this here is the slides array (i.e. $slides)              
    var this_duration = $(this[0]).data('duration') - 300;
    //prepare sizes and positions for all slide elements (i.e. background, and elements)
    processslide(this[0], slider_config, slides_original_fonts[0]);
    push.apply($slides, splice.call($slides, 0, 1));
    push.apply(slides_original_fonts, splice.call(slides_original_fonts, 0, 1));

    var next_slide = setTimeout(function(){ recycle.call($slides); }, this_duration);
    next_slide;

};
```

the function that is called above:

```
        function processslide(slide, slider_config, slide_original_fonts){

            fitslide(slide, slider_config, slide_original_fonts);

            animateslide.call(slide, slider_config, slide_original_fonts);

        };
```

The function to animate the slides is:

```
function animateslide(slide_config, slide_original_fonts){

    var current_width = $('#' + slider_config.id).parent().width();
    var percent_difference = current_width/slider_config.slider_width;
    var current_height = slider_config.slider_height * percent_difference;

    var z_counter = 2;

    var slide = $(this);
    var background = $($(this).children('.slidebg'));
    var slide_default = {
        easing  : 'swing',
        duration: 500,
        squares : 125,
        transition : 'fade',
        speedIn: 1000,
        speedOut: 300,
        yInit: parseInt(background.css('top').replace('px', '')),
        xInit: parseInt(background.css('left').replace('px', ''))                   
    };

    var _config = $.extend({}, $(this).data(), background.data());
    $.each(slide_default, function(k, m){ if(_config[k] == ''){ _config[k] = m; } });

    _config = $.extend({}, slide_config, slide_default, _config);
    var elements = $(this).find('.slide_elements').children();
    var elements_default = {
        easing: 'swing',
        speed: 500,
        start: 500,
        travel: 'fade',
        y: 0,
        x: 0

    };

    var elements_cummulative_time = _config.speedIn;
    background.css('z-index', z_counter);
    z_counter++;

    background.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        top: _config.yTravel,
        left: _config.xTravel 
        }, _config.speedIn, _config.easing, function(){

            var background = $(this);

            $(elements).each(function(i){
                var element = $(this);
                element.css('z-index', z_counter);
                z_counter++;
                var element_configuration = element.data();
                $.each(elements_default, function(l, o){ if(element_configuration[l] == '') element_configuration[l] = o; });
                element_configuration = $.extend({}, elements_default, element_configuration);
                elements_cummulative_time = elements_cummulative_time + element_configuration.start;

                setTimeout(function(){
                    element.animate({
                        opacity: 1,
                        top: percent_difference*element_configuration.y,
                        left: percent_difference*element_configuration.x
                    }, element_configuration.speed, element_configuration.easing);
                       }, element_configuration.start); 

            });
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        elements.animate({
            top: _config.yInit,
            left: _config.xInit
        }, _config.speedOut, _config.easing, function(){
            elements.each(function(){ $(this).css('z-index', 0)}); });

            //we remove the slide elements before we remove the background
    }, parseInt((_config.duration - 200) - _config.speedOut));

    setTimeout(function(){
        background.animate({
            top: _config.yInit,
            left: _config.xInit 
        }, _config.speedOut, _config.easing, function(){
            var currentTime= new Date();
            background.css('z-index', 0);
            fitslide(slide, slide_config, percent_difference, slide_original_fonts);
        });
    }, parseInt(_config.duration - _config.speedOut));

    $(window).resize( function(){
        console.log('STOPPING ELEMENTS');
        elements.stop(true);
        background.stop(true,true);
    });

};
```

ANDDDDDDDDDDDD the window resize functions:

```
function debouncer( recycle, timeout) {

                var timeoutID , timeout = timeout || 100;

                return function () {

                    var scope = this , args = $slides;
                    timeoutID = setTimeout( function () {

                        recycle.apply( scope , Array.prototype.slice.call( args ) ); } , timeout );
                                }

            };

            $(window).resize( debouncer( function ( e ) {
                    // do stuff 
            }));
```

Again, I am looking to accelerate current's slide animation to the end, and either trigger the setTimeout that set right after the current slide is animated (recycle function) or call the the recycle function in a different way to achieve the same end, both of these when the browser's screen is re-sized.

fiuuuuuu...  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are only two ways I know of to accelerate a jQuery animation:

1. Stop it where it is with `.stop(true)` and then start it again with the same end point, but a much shorter time duration.  That will appear to speed it up to the final result.
2. Use a custom easing function that you can dynamically change when conditions dictate.

The first option is probably a lot easier.

---

Timers can be cancelled with `clearTimeout()` if you've saved the timer id in a lasting variable.